# Is it safe to encrypt multiple files with the same strong passphrase?

Tags: gnupg, file-encryption, passphrase

I use `GPG` to symmetrically encrypt multiple files, and it would be more convenient if they all had the same strong passphrase. It's possible that someone could gain access to several of these files.

In this situation, I don't care if getting the passphrase for one of the files gives access to the others as well.

**Is it safe to use the same GPG symmetric passphrase for multiple files ?**

If needed, please assume `--cipher-algo AES256`, `--s2k-digest-algo SHA512` and `--s2k-count <something_big_enough>`.

Comment: To be clear, you're trying to determine if having access to multiple ciphertexts gives an attacker a better chance at figuring out the decryption key?

Comment: There's some info in this thread on the key derivation function used by GPG which might answer part of the question https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12321/what-is-the-gnupg-process-for-going-from-a-passphrase-to-a-symmetric-key. I say part, because it doesn't talk about AES encryption mode, the use of random IV, etc.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I'm concerned about pure crypto problems, not about the usual problems of password reuse.

Comment: I have the same question and wasn't able to find answer yet. 
It could be rephrased as "Is it easier to crack 2 files when we know that both have the same gpg AES passphrase when comparing to single file?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-13.9 OpenPG (and thus gpg) uses a variety of the CFB mode. Especially by prepending a full block of random data to the plaintext key reuse does not reveal additional information about the plaintext to an attacker.

<strike>As far as I understood gpg deterministically computes the key from the entered passphrase.</strike> (See comment from dave_thompson_085) And gpg also uses the same IV (all zeros) every time. But because of the used cipher mode the answer to your question is: yes, it is safe to use the same passphrase for multiple files if you don‘t care about the typical password reuse issues (but that‘s not the scope of this question).

Comment: OpenPGP has several s2k options, but GPG defaults to 3=salted+iterated: https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/OpenPGP-Options.html#index-s2k_002dmode (although you're right even without salt the random initial block would be enough)